# Getting an object or list of synonyms of a word through the web

Tags: javascript, json, html, api

Is there some web API to get a list of synonyms from a word?

Trying to do this all front-end, hopefully using JSON with some API.

The closet I have found is using this call

```
http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&callback=?&page=phone
```

which involves a lot more parsing through than I wish to do.  I was hoping there was some EASIER way to get a simple list of synonyms

Comment: Check http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9156

Comment: Just search for "thesaurus API" and you will get a bunch of results, e.g. http://www.openthesaurus.de/about/api, http://content.dictionary.com/api, http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php or http://thesaurus.altervista.org/